# programmatically Move and Check in local file to Sharepoint C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, sharepoint

Below is code I am using to programmatically move a local file from D: to sharepoint library. I am able to move the file, but it does not check the file into sharepoint. I am unsure how to check this file in. Has anyone had similar issues with sharepoint? Thanks.

Here is my code, I did not use the exact destination and source urls, so ignore that. It compiles and runs fine and it can be used to move a file from lets say D: to My documents, it jsut does not check the file into sharepoint.

Also I am checking in an excel sheet that performs a number of calculation based on data updated daily. The calculations are done through a macro. Is it possible to write a macro to upload automatically to sharepoint library and check in? if so i can add this to the macro already in place instead of using c#. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Net;
namespace defectUpload
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = "WS2016.xlsm";
        string sourcePath = @ source path "";
        string targetPath = @ destination path "" ;
        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destFile);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The provided code will not copy a file from local fs to sharepoint, and also never move a file in sharepoint.

Comment: System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destFile)

Comment: thats the last line i forgot to add

Comment: i am not trying to move a file in sharepoint, i am trying to upload a file into sharepoint, or add a newly updated sheet to sharepoint

Comment: You could use Powershell. When you are talking about a script, which language is it?

Comment: It is an excel sheet that perform calculations. I wrote a macro to perform all calculations and move all data. Before it calculates it copies the data required for calculations from another spreadsheet that is constantly being updated and pastes it to the final spreadsheet and performs calculations with latest data. This language is vba. But i would like to move that final calculated sheet to sharepoint which i think can be done with c#, i just dont know how to check in the file.

Comment: does that make sense? idk if i did a good job explaining. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was already solved in this post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133197/excel-vba-code-to-upload-document-into-sharepoint-online-2013

```
Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim LocalAddress As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object

' Where you will enter Sharepoint location path
SharepointAddress = "\\sharepoint path to document library"  & "\" 
 ' Where you will enter the file path, ex: Excel file
LocalAddress = "your file path"                                     
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
End If
Set objNet = Nothing
Set FS = Nothing
```

And also a good article on MSDN on this topic [Using Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services with the Microsoft Office System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159897(office.11).aspx).

There are also a lot of samples when you google for example for "vba upload to sharepoint"...

Comment: ok thanks, after editing that code it runs through completely but does not add to the sharepoint library. It gives no error messages. does the code above automatically check in ? would i need to enter network credentials?

Comment: In this case the code only copies a file to the sharepoint without checking in. This is not possible through VBA. It shouldnt ask for credentials.

Comment: do you know if its possible to check in with c#?

Comment: Of course. Look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467428.aspx

Comment: i havent worked much with sharepoint sdk. and apis. it seems there is a lot. how would i set up my project so i can use the code in the link above. I am having trouble adding references in visual studio 2015. I downloaded 2013 sdk, i am unsure what to do next. can i leave this project as console application or do i need to set up a new project as visual c# app for harepoint? where cna i find dll to reference and correct usings? thank you

Comment: You need to set up a development environment with a local SharePoint installation and Visual Studio. You can have a console application. That is no problem. I prefer looking at the following posts first http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/10/10/setting-up-a-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-101.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396